# Can Festivizers be applied to Specialized Killstreak weapons without removing the killstreak?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I saw a Strange Specialized Killstreak weapon I'm considering buying off the Steam Community Market, but I was wondering if I could use the Festivizer on it without removing the Killstreak.

The wiki said it kept qualities, so the Strange part still applied, but it mentioned nothing about keeping the killstreak on it.

Comment: According to a [patch released on December 6, 2013](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/December_6,_2013_Patch), they updated Killstreak Kits to work on Festive and Botkiller variants of target weapons.  Not quite sure if that answers your question or not - nor if it works both ways.

Comment: I'm looking for vice-versa, Applying Festivizers to Killstreak weapons.

Comment: Hence why I said I don't know if it works both ways. I would imagine it would, but I suppose the only way you'll find out is to try it (or someone will post an answer who has experience with the game/can find information better than me :) )

Comment: I learnt that Festivizers can actually only be used on certain items, and not the one I'm looking at, so I don't need the answer anymore. Leaving the topic up for other people who do face this problem however.

Answer (score 1):

In general:

Festivizers, name tags, description tags, filters, paint, strange parts, and killstreak kits (all 3 kinds) are all independent of each other. They can all be applied and removed independently of each other. 
The only exception is a strangifier, which when applied is permanent.

Answer (score 1):

I received my first festivizer recently and wanted to use it to festivize a weapon. To my surprise, only a few weapons could be used with the fesivizer.

Here's a link a later found with all the items you can use it with. Sadly, i can't just use it with anything. 
https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Template:Festivizer

For the weapon you were planning to use it with, make sure you CAN festivize it before buying it.